# .net - Signal to the Garbage Collector than an object is ready for removal?

Tags: .net, memory, garbage-collection

I was reading up on the performance of the .Net garbage collector, and I'm building a set of inter-referencing classes for my data model. I have implemented Delete() methods to dereference the object from all connected objects, ensuring that the object will be collectable.

While I do not currently know if this will be an issue for my application, I got to thinking about what would happen to objects that are promoted to later generations and then deleted. It is possible then that they would remain in memory for a long time.

Is it possible to tell the Garbage Collector that a particular object should be 'demoted' and freed during the next Gen0 collection?

Comment: Sure, just set the reference to the object to null. Or remove it from a collection, the more typical scenario. It isn't clear from your question which is appropriate but a Delete() method hints at the latter. No additional help is required.

Objects getting promoted to a later generation is not a problem. They just stay in memory a bit longer. Which is okay, they got promoted because they stayed in memory a bit longer in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the optimisations possible with a garbage collector is to leave objects unreferenced objects in memory for as long as possible thus deferring collection until it is absolutely necessary.  This can yield fewer collections and will mutualise the cost of the collection across more objects/memory.

Is it really a problem if your objects remain in memory for a long time after being dereferenced?  If your machine has enough free memory and your application's footprint after dereferencing is not growing is there really a downside?

The collection cost is a guaranteed cost whereas the cost of using extra memory is not certain - it may or may not impact your program/other programs.  The key point of this optimisation is that we give up a certain cost in exchange for an uncertain one.

Comment: I'd vote up, but I don't have enough reputation yet. Thanks for the explanation. But would it be helpful for the GC to know (in a hypothetical new revision of it) how much memory was available within a generation prior to attempting collection? Or does it have ways to guess at that already?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, the collector always knows how much memory is available within a generation prior to collection - not enough to be able to allocate more objects to that generation.

Comment: But it doesn't know how much memory in a generation is used up by garbage until it goes to collect it. It seems to me that it is possible for the GC to undergo many Gen0 collections continually when it could do a single Gen0+1 or Gen0+1+2 collection and reclaim much more memory, resulting in fewer collections to free the same amount of memory.

Comment: Except that the point of having multiple generations is to avoid having to collect the full heap each time (even if it would result in fewer collections).  Gen 0 collections are inexpensive relative to the later generations as gen 0 will only contain recently created objects.  On the other hand gen 1 collections will only be triggered after a gen 0 collections promotes objects and there is not enough space in the gen 1 heap to allocate store them.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from removing references to your object calling [`GC.Collect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.GC.Collect.aspx), you cannot manually interact with the GC.

Regarding this quote:

> While I do not currently know if this will be an issue for my application, I got to thinking about...

When it comes to GC in a managed language, until it's a problem, stop thinking about it. If you don't have a detailed understanding of the particular algorithms in use in the particular GC for your particular runtime, then you are more likely to *hurt* the performance of your application than help it by trying to modify the default behavior of the GC.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd vote up but I'm still too new. I guess I was more thinking of a way to hint to it that memory was available which it could take into account in deciding when to collect.